# BIS-B connection has to be Blackberry Alliance Program?

Tags: blackberry, connection

I'm totally new in the blackberry developing thing.

I already searched and reading a lot of threads in forum and in RIM tutorial itself.
I already become the member of Blackberry Alliance Program, the free one.

Then... I got confused about the BIS-B connection usage.
Is it true, I have to be the Associate (low level paid member) to access the BIS-B conenction to be applied in my application?

Thank you.

Comment: you can use it just by supplying the secret code, which has been all over the internet for years now and not so secret any more

Comment: hi.. thank you for answering the question. The suggested solution above is illegal, right? Is it illegal and widely used? What if, I as a developer use the secret code? what the drawback I will face? thank you.

Comment: One should be a lawyer to say whether this is illegal or not and what are the consequences. I think it is better to pass such decision to the customer (who pays you for the code) rather than to decide yourself. You (being a RIM partner) can also ask RIM directly about the right to use it.